# Programmatically databind listview while using datapager

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, datasource, datapager

I have a listview and two data pagers. My listview is hooked up to a data source whose data is ordered randomly. ORDER BY NEWID()

As you can imagine, each time I select a page or click next/prev page all the data is randomized making the datapager quite useless.

I figured I could set the datasource when the page is not posted back and then programmatically set the datasource to the listview but now when selecting a page or clicking the next/prev buttons, the page just simply doesn't change..

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim dv As DataView = sdsMembres.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)

        lvListMembres.DataSource = dv
        lvListMembres.DataBind()

        DataPager2.PagedControlID = "lvListMembres"
        DataPager3.PagedControlID = "lvListMembres"

        DataPager2.DataBind()
        DataPager3.DataBind()

    End If
End Sub
```

What am I missing / is there a better way to do this. The order by MUST be random and I MUST have the data pagers separate from the listview.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take the code between the If statement and place it in a separate function.

Add a method of storing the data, in this particular case I'll store it as a DataTable in a session.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' Clear datatable from session
        Session("CourtierList_dt") = Nothing
        ' Set datasource to listview and save in a session variable
        SetCourtierList()
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub SetCourtierList()
    Dim dt As DataTable
    If Session("CourtierList_dt") Is Nothing Then
        Dim dv As DataView = sdsMembres.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
        Session("CourtierList_dt") = dv.ToTable
    End If

    dt = Session("CourtierList_dt")

    lvListMembres.DataSource = dt
    lvListMembres.DataBind()

    DataPager2.PagedControlID = "lvListMembres"
    DataPager3.PagedControlID = "lvListMembres"

    DataPager2.DataBind()
    DataPager3.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Also, make sure to add the PagePropertiesChanging event to the listview

```
Protected Sub lvListMembres_PagePropertiesChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs) Handles lvListMembres.PagePropertiesChanging
    DataPager2.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, False)
    DataPager3.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, False)
    SetCourtierList()
End Sub
```

And there you have it, hope this is helpful for someone.